# grep for multiple elements of an array

Tags: shell-script, dd, array

I am trying to write a dd migration script that will do the following:

1. read user input (max=4) into an array, called "array". the user will enter the logical volume names to be migrated.
2. once each element is stored on an array, run:

`/sbin/lvscan | grep -E '"array[0]"|"array[1]"|"array[2]"|"array[3]"’`

3. spawn multiple ssh connections to migrate each logical volume via dd to a specific host, the IP of which is also entered by user and stored in a variable.

I currently have:

```
#!/bin/bash

 echo "Enter upto 4 SRVID's seperated by a space"


 while read SRVIDS 
 do


        [ "$SRVIDS" == "done" ] && break
        array=("${array[@]}" $SRVIDS)

 done



 /sbin/lvscan | grep -E '"array[0]"|"array[1]"|"array[2]"|"array[3]"' 2&>1
```

What am I doing wrong? I am unable to get grep for the logical volume paths.

Comment: Variables/arays names are not expanded under single quotes, you need to remove them. Also add `$` in front of their names.

Comment: Getting the volume names on the command line would make the script more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

No need to list ALL the array elements; try:

```
IFS="|"
grep -E "${array[*]}"
```

Don't forget to save old `IFS` and then restore it...

Comment: ... or do it in a subshell.